# Access denied to my MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a fresh new DB ("rpgame") in MySQL on my linux server - but I'm getting access denied errors when trying to connect to it. The user it's connecting as is root@play.runic-paradise.com.

I've tried debugging a bit, please see the screenshot. It seems that the password area is missing for the entry I'm trying to login as. Is that a problem? Anyone know how I can fix it? [image: mysql user access dump]

if that's appearing as small for you as it is for me, try this link:
[runic-paradise.com/files/sampledb.png](http://runic-paradise.com/files/sampledb.png)

Comment: Google: mysql change password and try it out?

Comment: Is root@ each of the hostnames considered a unique user to MySQL?

Comment: @PeeHaa -  Ok used SET PASSWORD FOR 'user-name-here'@'hostname-name-here' = PASSWORD('new-password-here');   -- and the entry is no longer blank.  Now to try it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have never set a root password for MySQL server, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root. To setup root password for first time, use mysqladmin command at shell prompt as follows:

Setting root user password

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Verifying its working

```
$ mysql -u root -p'PASSWORD' db-name-here
```